# how to make a mandatory field on FileMaker pro?

Tags: filemaker

I'm new to FileMaker pro and I want to make one of the fields a mandatory field where the user can't save his data without filling out that specific field. 
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often it is sufficient to guide users attention to this field by conditional formatting. If field is empty, background gets a pink color ...

Answer (score 2):

Validate the field as 'Not empty':
http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/create_db.8.24.html#1029602

Advanced stuff:
If you like, add an OnObjectValidate script trigger to handle the user interaction yourself (the built-in validation error message can be rather intimidating). However, that's in addition to the above - not instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not empty validation would work.

If you are publishing a web form, you could write a script that validates all fields when the submit button is pressed. Let me know if this is of interest to you and I can provide more details.